# Is there a command line tool to split a SAM/BAM file by CB (cell barcode) tag?

Tags: sam, single-cell, data-preprocessing

I have a BAM file from a single cell sequencing experiment. Each read has had the cell barcode annotated in the `CB` tag. Some reads do not have a `CB` tag. For each of an arbitrary set of barcodes, I would like to split out the reads for each of those barcodes into a separate file. Is there a tool that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a package called sinto (https://github.com/timoast/sinto) that contains a function to split a BAM file into different files based on the cell barcodes.

The [installation](https://timoast.github.io/sinto/installation.html) can be done via anaconda:

```
conda create -p conda/envs/sinto python=3.8 sinto
```

And a [usage example from the documentation](https://timoast.github.io/sinto/basic_usage.html#filter-cell-barcodes-from-bam-file) is:

```
sinto filterbarcodes -b my_bam.bam -c my_barcodes.txt --barcodetag "CB"
```

Where the `my_barcodes.txt` file contains cluster names in a tab separated list format:

```
TGGCAATGTTGAAGCG-1  A
GACCAATCACCATTCC-1  A
CAGGATTCAGAACTTC-1  B
GAACCTAAGAGAGGTA-1  B,A
..
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a [python script](https://gist.github.com/winni2k/978b33d62fee5e3484ec757de1a00412) based on pysam that is free for anyone to use:

````py
"""
MIT License
Copyright (c) 2020 Warren W. Kretzschmar
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.
THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
SOFTWARE.
"""

from pathlib import Path

import pysam


class BamWriter:
    def __init__(self, alignment, barcodes, prefix):
        self.alignment = alignment
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.barcodes = set(barcodes)
        self._out_files = {}

    def write_record_to_barcode(self, rec, barcode):
        if barcode not in self.barcodes:
            return
        if barcode not in self._out_files:
            self._open_file_for_barcode(barcode)
        self._out_files[barcode].write(rec)

    def _open_file_for_barcode(self, barcode):
        self._out_files[barcode] = pysam.AlignmentFile(
            f"{self.prefix}_{barcode}.bam", "wb", template=self.alignment
        )


def main(input_bam, barcodes_file, output_prefix, contigs):
    """Split a 10x barcoded sequencing file into barcode-specific BAMs

    input:
    barcodes_file: a file containing barcodes or a single barcode
    contigs: '.' for all contigs, 'chr1' for the contig 'chr1',
    or '1-5' for chromosomes 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5
    """
    alignment = pysam.AlignmentFile(input_bam)
    if Path(barcodes_file).is_file():
        with open(barcodes_file, "r") as fh:
            barcodes = [l.rstrip() for l in fh.readlines()]
    else:
        barcodes = [barcodes_file]
        print(f"Extracting single barcode: {barcodes}")
    writer = BamWriter(alignment=alignment, barcodes=barcodes, prefix=output_prefix)
    if contigs == ".":
        print("Extracting reads from all contigs")
        recs = alignment.fetch()
    else:
        if "-" in contigs:
            start, end = contigs.split("-")
            print(f"Extracting reads from contigs {start} to {end}")
            recs = (alignment.fetch(str(contig)) for contig in range(start, end + 1))
        elif "," in contigs:
            contigs = contigs.split(",")
            print(f"Extracting reads from contigs {contigs}")
            recs = (alignment.fetch(str(contig)) for contig in contigs)
        else:
            print("Extracting reads for one contig: {contigs}")
            recs = (alignment.fetch(c) for c in [contigs])

    for rec in recs:
        try:
            barcode = rec.get_tag("CB")
            writer.write_record_to_barcode(rec=rec, barcode=barcode)
        except KeyError:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    main(
        input_bam=sys.argv[1],
        barcodes_file=sys.argv[2],
        output_prefix=sys.argv[3],
        contigs=sys.argv[4],
    )
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can do it [with samtools](https://kb.10xgenomics.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022448251-How-to-filter-the-BAM-file-produced-by-10x-pipelines-with-a-list-of-barcodes-):

```
# Save the header lines
samtools view -H $BAM_FILE > SAM_header

# Filter alignments using filter.txt. Use LC_ALL=C to set C locale instead of UTF-8
samtools view $BAM_FILE | LC_ALL=C grep -F -f filter.txt > filtered_SAM_body

# Combine header and body
cat SAM_header filtered_SAM_body > filtered.sam

# Convert filtered.sam to BAM format
samtools view -b filtered.sam > filtered.bam
```

And 10x Genomics has developed [subset-bam](https://github.com/10XGenomics/subset-bam) a tool that can split a BAM file by barcode.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a lot of cores:

10x has [subset-bam](https://github.com/10XGenomics/subset-bam) a pretty fast way to pull out all the cells with a specific CB/BX if you only need a small number.